# How to attach screenshot to protractor's HTML report?

Tags: automation, protractor, reporting

In my `protractor` project, i am trying to take an screenshot, and attach it to my `html` report. The process of taking screenshot is happening in an `After` ***hook***, as below:

```
import {  Status,After, HookScenarioResult} from 'cucumber';
import {browser} from 'protractor';
import { async } from 'q';

After(async  (scenario:HookScenarioResult)=> {

    if(scenario.result.status===Status.FAILED){
        const screenshot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
        this.attach(screenshot,"image/png");
    }
});
```

But in the line `this.attach(screenshot,"image/png");`, it complains with:

```
TypeError: this.attach is not a function
```

***What is the problem?***

My config is:

```
   "cucumber": "^5.1.0",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^4.0.4",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.1.1",
```

Comment: problem with `this`. Also you should remove import for `async`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved, by changing the fat function to normal one. I still, do not understand why it affects my code, but is working well now, and i have screenshot on my html report.

```
After(async function(scenario) {
    if (scenario.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
        // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
            const screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
            this.attach(screenShot, "image/png");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi your code works for me..but image is not getting loaded in report.. it is showing broken.. do you have any idea on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code working for me:

```
  After(function(scenarioResult) {
    let self = this;
    if (scenarioResult.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
    return browser.takeScreenshot()
    .then(function (screenshot) {
        const decodedImage = new Buffer(screenshot.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, ''), 'base64');
        self.attach(decodedImage, 'image/png');
    });
}
});
```